# positioning inline-block DIV`s inside a DIV container (without flexbox)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically position two divs (1&2), set to '**display: inline-block**'. Can't understand  why vertical-align doesn't want to work?

Ps. Don't want to use flexbox...

```html
<div>
  <div id="div1">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
         </span>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
         </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.parent > * {
  display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#div1,
#div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div id="div1">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
     </span>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
     </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add one more parent div and give **display:table** and for the immediate child set **display:table-cell** then give  **vertical-align:middle;**. Please see the code.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn`t working as the height of DIV hasnt been set! After setting height of DIV, vertical alignment of other one started working.